# Do I need to create a child theme for JointsWP

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I have decided to try o move away from buying bloated premade themes and build my own from scratch.

I am planning to use JointsWP along with Elementor Pro page builder.
When I install a bough theme, I always install a child theme where I do all my customisation.

My question is this:
Do I need to create a child theme for JointsWP?

Does anyone know if I will get theme update notification the same way I do know with my bough theme?

Thank you

Comment: "build my own from scratch", well your not doing that if your using JointsWP and Elementor Pro.  I would imagine you would still use a child theme, as joints is a theme and if you update it you would lose updates made directly to the theme.

Comment: I agree with RiddleMeThis. Good approach, wrong execution. Build your own theme and then rely on 3rd party is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean this JointsWP, https://github.com/JeremyEnglert/JointsWP/, then no. You don't need to use a child theme as per the theme description

> This theme is meant to be your starting point, not the end product. No
>   need to use child themes.
>   ...
>   Save time and modernize your workflow with the included Gulp setup.
>   With just a few commands, you can quickly compile Sass files, minify
>   JS files, watch files for changes and so much more.

You should just use it as a starting point and customize it to match you exact needs - add what you need and remove what you don't. The updates you can install, if you want, are the ones published by Zurb to the Foundation framework, which you can install by npm.

The theme author has also written a blog post regarding updating the theme, https://materiell.com/2016/04/dont-need-update-jointswp-foundation/

*I'm not affiliated with JointsWP, but I've used it on many occasions to build custom themes.*

Comment: very true, however, if you think you will only make a few changes before downloading an updated version of JointsWP and starting over it might make sense to keep using a child theme for now.